# How to get count or records returned from json_agg() query?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jsonb

I am dynamically building up some queries that look like this

```
select array_to_json(array_agg(t)) from (
select 
a.field_1,
a.field_2,
jsonb_agg(distinct jsonb_build_object('id',g.id,'data',g.fullname)) as field_4,
jsonb_agg(distinct jsonb_build_object('id',i.optionid,'data',i.option)) as field_9,
jsonb_agg(distinct jsonb_build_object('id',c.id,'data',c.fullname)) as field_6,
jsonb_agg(distinct jsonb_build_object('id',k.id,'data',k.fullname)) as field_8,
jsonb_agg(distinct jsonb_build_object('id',m.id,'data',m.field_20)) as field_21,
l.field_5,
jsonb_agg(distinct jsonb_build_object('id',e.optionid,'data',e.option,'attributes',e.attributes)) as field_23,
n.data as field_13,
jsonb_agg(distinct jsonb_build_object('id',bb.id,'data',bb.fullname)) as field_12

from schema_1.tbl_342 a
left join schema_1.tbl_342_to_tbl_329_field_10 b on a.id=b.tbl_342_id
left join schema_1.tbl_329_customid c on b.tbl_329_id=c.id
left join schema_1.tbl_329 m on m.id=b.tbl_329_id
left join schema_1.tbl_329_field_23_join d on c.id=d.id
left join schema_1.tbl_329_field_23 e on d.optionid = e.optionid
left join schema_1.tbl_342_to_tbl_312_field_4 f on a.id=f.tbl_342_id
left join schema_1.tbl_312_customid g on f.tbl_312_id = g.id
left join schema_1.tbl_342_field_9_join h on h.id=a.id
left join schema_1.tbl_342_field_9 i on i.optionid=h.optionid
left join schema_1.tbl_343_to_tbl_342_field_6 j on j.tbl_342_id=a.id
left join schema_1.tbl_343_customid k on j.tbl_343_id=k.id
left join schema_1.tbl_343 l on l.id=j.tbl_343_id
left join schema_1.tbl_342_field_13_max n on n.id=a.id
group by a.field_1,a.field_2,l.field_5,m.field_23,n.data
) t
```

an Example of output comes back as follows

```
[{"field_1":"Billy","field_2":null,"field_4":[{"id": 4, "data": "Senior Javascript Engineer"}, {"id": 5, "data": "Recruiter"}],"field_9":[{"id": 1, "data": "Blue"}],"field_6":[{"id": 32, "data": "Nancy - 32"}],"field_8":[{"id": null, "data": null}],"field_21":[{"id": 32, "data": "ggñ@cnn.com"}],"field_5":null,"field_23":[{"id": 5, "data": "Expert", "attributes": {"text": "#FFFFFF", "color": "#448AFF"}}],"field_13":"Expert"},{"field_1":"Jackson","field_2":null,"field_4":[{"id": 2, "data": "Marketing Manager M1004"}, {"id": 4, "data": "Senior Javascript Engineer"}, {"id": 5, "data": "Recruiter"}],"field_9":[{"id": 3, "data": "Red"}],"field_6":[{"id": 36, "data": ",Mike - 36"}],"field_8":[{"id": 2, "data": "Henry"}],"field_21":[{"id": 36, "data": "PtereSwanson@gmail.com"}],"field_5":"CA","field_23":[{"id": 6, "data": "Guru", "attributes": {"text": "#FFFFFF", "color": "#0D47A1"}}],"field_13":"Guru"},{"field_1":"Jacob","field_2":null,"field_4":[{"id": null, "data": null}],"field_9":[{"id": null, "data": null}],"field_6":[{"id": null, "data": null}],"field_8":[{"id": null, "data": null}],"field_21":[{"id": null, "data": null}],"field_5":null,"field_23":[{"id": null, "data": null, "attributes": null}],"field_13":null},{"field_1":"John","field_2":null,"field_4":[{"id": null, "data": null}],"field_9":[{"id": 2, "data": "Green"}],"field_6":[{"id": 32, "data": "Nancy - 32"}, {"id": 35, "data": "Bobby - 35"}],"field_8":[{"id": null, "data": null}],"field_21":[{"id": 32, "data": "ggñ@cnn.com"}, {"id": 35, "data": "Oliver@yahoo.com"}],"field_5":null,"field_23":[{"id": 4, "data": "Experienced", "attributes": {"text": "#FFFFFF", "color": "#C79702"}}, {"id": 5, "data": "Expert", "attributes": {"text": "#FFFFFF", "color": "#448AFF"}}],"field_13":"Expert"},{"field_1":"Todd","field_2":null,"field_4":[{"id": null, "data": null}],"field_9":[{"id": 4, "data": "Yellow"}],"field_6":[{"id": 1, "data": "Bobbie - 1"}, {"id": 4, "data": "bobby - 4"}],"field_8":[{"id": 1, "data": "Please stand up"}],"field_21":[{"id": 1, "data": "paul@sonos.com"}, {"id": 4, "data": "ggñ@cnn.com"}],"field_5":"MA","field_23":[{"id": 2, "data": "Novice", "attributes": {"text": "#000000", "color": "#FFEB3B"}}, {"id": 3, "data": "Intermediate", "attributes": {"text": "#000000", "color": "#F5F5F5"}}],"field_13":"Intermediate"}]
```

Here is output I want to get.

```
{count: 5, data:[{"field_1":"Billy","field_2":null,"field_4":[{"id": 4, "data": "Senior Javascript Engineer"}, {"id": 5, "data": "Recruiter"}],"field_9":[{"id": 1, "data": "Blue"}],"field_6":[{"id": 32, "data": "Nancy - 32"}],"field_8":[{"id": null, "data": null}],"field_21":[{"id": 32, "data": "ggñ@cnn.com"}],"field_5":null,"field_23":[{"id": 5, "data": "Expert", "attributes": {"text": "#FFFFFF", "color": "#448AFF"}}],"field_13":"Expert"},{"field_1":"Jackson","field_2":null,"field_4":[{"id": 2, "data": "Marketing Manager M1004"}, {"id": 4, "data": "Senior Javascript Engineer"}, {"id": 5, "data": "Recruiter"}],"field_9":[{"id": 3, "data": "Red"}],"field_6":[{"id": 36, "data": ",Mike - 36"}],"field_8":[{"id": 2, "data": "Henry"}],"field_21":[{"id": 36, "data": "PtereSwanson@gmail.com"}],"field_5":"CA","field_23":[{"id": 6, "data": "Guru", "attributes": {"text": "#FFFFFF", "color": "#0D47A1"}}],"field_13":"Guru"},{"field_1":"Jacob","field_2":null,"field_4":[{"id": null, "data": null}],"field_9":[{"id": null, "data": null}],"field_6":[{"id": null, "data": null}],"field_8":[{"id": null, "data": null}],"field_21":[{"id": null, "data": null}],"field_5":null,"field_23":[{"id": null, "data": null, "attributes": null}],"field_13":null},{"field_1":"John","field_2":null,"field_4":[{"id": null, "data": null}],"field_9":[{"id": 2, "data": "Green"}],"field_6":[{"id": 32, "data": "Nancy - 32"}, {"id": 35, "data": "Bobby - 35"}],"field_8":[{"id": null, "data": null}],"field_21":[{"id": 32, "data": "ggñ@cnn.com"}, {"id": 35, "data": "Oliver@yahoo.com"}],"field_5":null,"field_23":[{"id": 4, "data": "Experienced", "attributes": {"text": "#FFFFFF", "color": "#C79702"}}, {"id": 5, "data": "Expert", "attributes": {"text": "#FFFFFF", "color": "#448AFF"}}],"field_13":"Expert"},{"field_1":"Todd","field_2":null,"field_4":[{"id": null, "data": null}],"field_9":[{"id": 4, "data": "Yellow"}],"field_6":[{"id": 1, "data": "Bobbie - 1"}, {"id": 4, "data": "bobby - 4"}],"field_8":[{"id": 1, "data": "Please stand up"}],"field_21":[{"id": 1, "data": "paul@sonos.com"}, {"id": 4, "data": "ggñ@cnn.com"}],"field_5":"MA","field_23":[{"id": 2, "data": "Novice", "attributes": {"text": "#000000", "color": "#FFEB3B"}}, {"id": 3, "data": "Intermediate", "attributes": {"text": "#000000", "color": "#F5F5F5"}}],"field_13":"Intermediate"}]}
```

I'd like to have the total records returned in a top level attribute, separate from the data results.
How would I do that, I tried adding `count(a.id)` which is the base table, but it doesn't return total records.

Comment: Sample data and desired output is required to get the exact query

Comment: Ok, I updated ticket with example of current output, and then what I'd like to generate. Let me know if that's enough.

Comment: added the answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "*total records*"? Would just `select count(t), array_to_json(array_agg(t)) as data from (…) t` do the trick?

Comment: Btw I would suggest to use subqueries with `jsonb_agg` in the `SELECT`, instead of those many `LEFT JOIN`s, to get a more readable query structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `json_array_length` as your final out put is in `JSON Array` format.

```
select jsonb_build_object('count',json_array_length(data),'data',data) from (
select array_to_json(array_agg(t)) data from (
select 
a.field_1,
a.field_2,
jsonb_agg(distinct jsonb_build_object('id',g.id,'data',g.fullname)) as field_4,
jsonb_agg(distinct jsonb_build_object('id',i.optionid,'data',i.option)) as field_9,
jsonb_agg(distinct jsonb_build_object('id',c.id,'data',c.fullname)) as field_6,
jsonb_agg(distinct jsonb_build_object('id',k.id,'data',k.fullname)) as field_8,
jsonb_agg(distinct jsonb_build_object('id',m.id,'data',m.field_20)) as field_21,
l.field_5,
jsonb_agg(distinct jsonb_build_object('id',e.optionid,'data',e.option,'attributes',e.attributes)) as field_23,
n.data as field_13,
jsonb_agg(distinct jsonb_build_object('id',bb.id,'data',bb.fullname)) as field_12

from schema_1.tbl_342 a
left join schema_1.tbl_342_to_tbl_329_field_10 b on a.id=b.tbl_342_id
left join schema_1.tbl_329_customid c on b.tbl_329_id=c.id
left join schema_1.tbl_329 m on m.id=b.tbl_329_id
left join schema_1.tbl_329_field_23_join d on c.id=d.id
left join schema_1.tbl_329_field_23 e on d.optionid = e.optionid
left join schema_1.tbl_342_to_tbl_312_field_4 f on a.id=f.tbl_342_id
left join schema_1.tbl_312_customid g on f.tbl_312_id = g.id
left join schema_1.tbl_342_field_9_join h on h.id=a.id
left join schema_1.tbl_342_field_9 i on i.optionid=h.optionid
left join schema_1.tbl_343_to_tbl_342_field_6 j on j.tbl_342_id=a.id
left join schema_1.tbl_343_customid k on j.tbl_343_id=k.id
left join schema_1.tbl_343 l on l.id=j.tbl_343_id
left join schema_1.tbl_342_field_13_max n on n.id=a.id
group by a.field_1,a.field_2,l.field_5,m.field_23,n.data
) t)x
```

It will give you the desired output

**UPDATE as per comment**

```
with cte as (
select 
a.field_1,
a.field_2,
jsonb_agg(distinct jsonb_build_object('id',g.id,'data',g.fullname)) as field_4,
jsonb_agg(distinct jsonb_build_object('id',i.optionid,'data',i.option)) as field_9,
jsonb_agg(distinct jsonb_build_object('id',c.id,'data',c.fullname)) as field_6,
jsonb_agg(distinct jsonb_build_object('id',k.id,'data',k.fullname)) as field_8,
jsonb_agg(distinct jsonb_build_object('id',m.id,'data',m.field_20)) as field_21,
l.field_5,
jsonb_agg(distinct jsonb_build_object('id',e.optionid,'data',e.option,'attributes',e.attributes)) as field_23,
n.data as field_13,
jsonb_agg(distinct jsonb_build_object('id',bb.id,'data',bb.fullname)) as field_12

from schema_1.tbl_342 a
left join schema_1.tbl_342_to_tbl_329_field_10 b on a.id=b.tbl_342_id
left join schema_1.tbl_329_customid c on b.tbl_329_id=c.id
left join schema_1.tbl_329 m on m.id=b.tbl_329_id
left join schema_1.tbl_329_field_23_join d on c.id=d.id
left join schema_1.tbl_329_field_23 e on d.optionid = e.optionid
left join schema_1.tbl_342_to_tbl_312_field_4 f on a.id=f.tbl_342_id
left join schema_1.tbl_312_customid g on f.tbl_312_id = g.id
left join schema_1.tbl_342_field_9_join h on h.id=a.id
left join schema_1.tbl_342_field_9 i on i.optionid=h.optionid
left join schema_1.tbl_343_to_tbl_342_field_6 j on j.tbl_342_id=a.id
left join schema_1.tbl_343_customid k on j.tbl_343_id=k.id
left join schema_1.tbl_343 l on l.id=j.tbl_343_id
left join schema_1.tbl_342_field_13_max n on n.id=a.id
group by a.field_1,a.field_2,l.field_5,m.field_23,n.data
),
cte2 as 
(select count(*) as "count_" from cte)

select row_to_json(x) from (
select cte2.count_ "count", array_to_json(array_agg(t)) as data from (
select * from cte limit 3 -- you can add desired limit here
 ) t, cte2
group by 1
)x
```

Comment: Well, I actually need the count from the query because I will be adding where clause and because ultimately, I will return a limited number of records from a larger recordset. For example, the query may be 15,000 records match, but what is returned is the first 500 records. In this example, I want to show 15,000, the total matching records from the query. How would i do that?

Comment: you can add where clause before group by

Comment: yes, but won't your function, json_array_length(data) return 500 in my example, not 15,000?

Comment: means you want total count of records and then only data filtered by where clause?

Comment: as example, I will add limit 500 to the above query. So, even though matching records could be 15,000, i'll bring back first 500, and will have paging to get to next 500 and so forth. but when the query is run, I want to showing total records of query. Maybe this can only be done with 2 separate queries

Comment: quick question, in this scenario, would the server still need to retrieve the 15,000 before applying the limit ? I'm just wondering if this will provide proper performance if recordset is really large, say hundreds of thousands of records, but we are just showing the top 500

Comment: Yes. i suggest use 2 calls instead. one for count and second for data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220664/discussion-between-akhilesh-mishra-and-mike-hennessy).